# Could there be some system of units such that all fundamental constants are 1?

Tags: physical-constants, absolute-units

The fundamental constants in physics have extremely low values because of our scale compared to fundamental particles. Could there be such a system of units such that all fundamental constants are 1?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units

Comment: @probably_someone that's not what I'm looking for, Planck units are derived from the fundamental constants

Comment: In Planck units, the fundamental constants are set to 1. $G=\hbar=c=k_B=k_e=1$. That's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @probably_someone I'll have to read up in that, I might have some misconceptions to clear up, sorry for being a bit aggressive

Comment: I think in order for this to be a good question, it would have to show that you are aware of the existence of Planck units, you considered them as a candidate for the system you're seeking, and for some reason they turned out to be unsuitable. We need to know what that reason is. Without all that, I think the question is not sufficiently researched and also may not be specified well enough to answer.

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current form. What do you mean by "all" the fundamental constants? Does the Coulomb constant $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ count? What about the permittivity of free space, $\epsilon_0$? They're both fundamental constants, but they cannot both be unity in any given system.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe there can (although this depends which physical constants you include).

The problem is that there are fundamental physical constants like the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) $\alpha$ that are dimensionless and have the same numeric value ($\alpha \simeq 1/137$) in all systems of units.

Since $\alpha$ can be expressed in terms of a combination of the speed of light, Planck's constant, the permittivity of free space and the electric charge, then it isn't possible to set all of these to unity simultaneously. For example, in Planck units, where $\hbar =G= c = (4\pi\epsilon_0)^{-1}= 1$, then $\alpha = e^2$, which thus defines the electric charge to be $\sqrt{\alpha}$.

There are other dimensionless coupling constants, such as the [gravitational coupling constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_coupling_constant) $\alpha_G$ that involves $G$, the mass of an electron, the speed of light and Planck's constant. Even in Planck units you still have something left over that must be given a non-unity value; in this case the electron mass, such that $m_e =\sqrt{\alpha_G}$.

Comment: This makes sense. Any system in which you could set $\alpha$ to 1 is a system in which QED no longer makes any sense as a perturbative theory, which would be very bad.

Answer (score -4):

no it can not be possible because we define a constant by a basic equation and the same thing can be included in other fundamental constant equation so all constants can not be one

Comment: -1. Please clarify your answer so that it is clear as to what you are trying to say. If possible, site references for your claims and try a bit of a punctuation.